# Wallaby Ecto.Registry.lookup error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, wallaby

I'm trying to get [Wallaby](https://github.com/keathley/wallaby) working on a new Phoenix project. I've followed the setup instructions in the readme, but when I try to run a basic test I get an Ecto registry error:

```
1) test home page has welcome message (WallabyTestWeb.HomePageTest)
     test/wallaby_test_web/features/home_page_test.exs:6
     ** (ArgumentError) argument error
     stacktrace:
       (stdlib) :ets.lookup_element(Ecto.Registry, nil, 3)
       (ecto) lib/ecto/registry.ex:18: Ecto.Registry.lookup/1
       (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql/sandbox.ex:529: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.proxy_pool/1
       (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql/sandbox.ex:469: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.checkout/2
       (wallaby_test) test/support/feature_case.ex:18: WallabyTestWeb.FeatureCase.__ex_unit_setup_0/1
       (wallaby_test) test/support/feature_case.ex:1: WallabyTestWeb.FeatureCase.__ex_unit__/2
       test/wallaby_test_web/features/home_page_test.exs:1: WallabyTestWeb.HomePageTest.__ex_unit__/2
```

Here's the failing test:

```
defmodule WallabyTestWeb.HomePageTest do
  use WallabyTestWeb.FeatureCase, async: true

  import Wallaby.Query

  test "home page has welcome message", %{session: session} do
    require IEx
    IEx.pry()

    session
    |> visit("/")
    |> assert_has(css("h2", text: "Welcome to Phoenix!"))
  end
end
```

Here's the feature case:

```
defmodule WallabyTestWeb.FeatureCase do
  use ExUnit.CaseTemplate

  using do
    quote do
      use Wallaby.DSL

      alias WallabyTestWeb.Repo
      import Ecto
      import Ecto.Changeset
      import Ecto.Query

      import WallabyTestWeb.Router.Helpers
    end
  end

  setup tags do
    :ok = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.checkout(WallabyTestWeb.Repo)

    unless tags[:async] do
      Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode(WallabyTestWeb.Repo, {:shared, self()})
    end

    metadata = Phoenix.Ecto.SQL.Sandbox.metadata_for(WallabyTestWeb.Repo, self())
    {:ok, session} = Wallaby.start_session(metadata: metadata)
    {:ok, session: session}
  end
end
```

Here's the entire PR with my setup changes: https://github.com/marcdel/wallaby_test/pull/1/files

I'm using Elixir 1.6, PhantomJs 2.1.1.

```
$ elixir --version
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.1.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Elixir 1.6.0-dev (882c2bd) (compiled with OTP 20)

$ brew info phantomjs
phantomjs: stable 2.1.1 (bottled)
```

Comment: Show us the context around `features/home_page_test.exs:6` please.

Comment: @mudasobwa added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a copy/paste issue

My repo is in a separate app so in FeatureCase I replaced `WallabyTestWeb.Repo` with `WallabyTest.Repo`, and now the tests are happy!

e: the tip off was that I was only getting Postgres errors in the logs when running the test, not when doing `mix ecto.reset`.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not the issue with your test suite, because this issue is quite frequent when using Elixir 1.5 or higher and Phoenix 1.3. Propably somewhere above in logs you might find something like this:

```
** (DBConnection.OwnershipError) cannot find ownership process for 
#PID....
```

Try to run all the migrations for `TEST` environment and then re-run the tests. You can do it with one command:

```
MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.reset && mix test
```

`ecto.reset` will reset your database (check your `mix.exs` file), which is an alias for recreating your database, migrating it and running seeds again.

Comment: No dice, unfortunately.

In `/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log` I see the following when reseting and running the tests:

`ERROR:  database "cheese_log_test" already exists`
`STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE "cheese_log_test" ENCODING 'UTF8'`

Comment: This is the cause then. Your psql account can't delete this db, probably doesn't have other permissions too, so your repo tests don't work. In  error log it's clear that ecto is the reason of failed tests.